# Android - Delete or cancel notification before it shows up

Tags: java, android, notifications

Let's say a notification using `AlarmManager` was set at a specific date. What if I want to delete that notification with a button press before it has even appeared. The `NotificationManager.cancel(id)` method if I'm not mistaken will cancel a notification that is currently showing. What if I want to delete it before it has even appeared? Like how you remove an item in an arraylist or how you delete a row in a database.

---

Example I have a `Person`object with `id,name` and everytime I add a `Person`to the database, a `Notification` will be set on a specified date.

Here is the set notification method to be called with a calendar instance of a specified date and a person object:

```
 public void setNotification(Calendar calendar,Person person){
    AlarmManager alertManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    intent.putExtra("myTag",person);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, person.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alertManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

My alarm receiver class (Yes I'm implementing DAO design pattern. I have a PersonDao and PersonDaoImpl with the latter being a singleton class):

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
final static String GROUP_KEY = "GROUP_KEY";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve info:
    PersonDAO personDao = PersonDAOImpl.getInstance(context);
    Person person = (Person)intent.getSerializableExtra("myTag");
    String name = person.getName();
    long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 300, 0, 300};

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ViewDetails.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    int requestCode = person.getId();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(requestCode, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Deadline due today")
            .setContentText("name: " + name)
            .setTicker(name+"'s debt is due today")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)

            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(requestCode, notification);


}
```

Example the date set on the alarm reciever was September 12 2016 3:00pm. The current date is Septermber 10 2016. What I want to do is when I delete the person in the database, **the notification will be deleted/canceled also** therefore on September 12 2016 3:00pm there will no longer be an alarm notification.

Comment: "a notification was set at a specific date" -- that is not a feature of `Notification`. You might wish to provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are attempting to do this.

Comment: using alarm manager @CommonsWare

Comment: @Andre Post complete example of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cancel something that you scheduled via `AlarmManager`, call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`, passing in an equivalent `PendingIntent` to the one that you used to schedule the work in the first place. Here, by "equivalent `PendingIntent`", I mean:

- the same operation (e.g., `getActivity()` vs. `getService()` vs. `getBroadcast()`)
- the same request code (2nd parameter to those methods)
- an equivalent `Intent`

By "equivalent `Intent`", I mean:

- the same component
- the same action
- the same MIME type
- the same categories
- the same data (`Uri`)

for whatever of those properties you had set on the original `Intent` for the original `PendingIntent`.

Comment: But I understand your answer :) I'll try when I wake up i'll sleep first thank you

Comment: Does this include to match same flags and extra data that were set too?

Comment: @Ayyappa: No, flags and extras should not matter in this case.